# What's the point of union type A | B where B is a subclass of A?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am familiar with object oriented programming, union types, and covariance/contravariance, but relatively new to Typescript.

I've inherited an old project (Typescript 3.2) with the following code:

```js
class A {
  public foo: string
}

class B extends A {
  public bar: string
}

function foo(obj: A | B) {
  return obj.foo
}

const array: (A | B)[] = [new A(), new B()]
```

There are hundreds of places in the codebase which use `A | B`. As far as I can tell, this is completely redundant, because any instance of `B` is also an instance of `A`. Functions and arrays are covariant in Typescript, so why not do this, which is simpler and compiles just fine:

```js
function foo(obj: A) {
  return obj.foo
}

const array: A[] = [new A(), new B()]
```

Am I missing something? Is there any situation where this is useful?

Comment: B is instance of A, but A is not instance of B

Comment: That is almost tautologically true. Can you give an example of how this matters with regards to union types, given that functions and arrays are covariant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If TypeScript's type system were fully "correct" then whenever `X extends Y`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `X | Y` should reduce to `Y`, known as *subtype collapsing*.  (And likewise, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `X & Y` should reduce to `X`.  These are forms of [absorption laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_unions_and_intersections).)

And depending on the particular `X` and `Y` types, this *does* happen in TypeScript.  In particular, primitive types mostly behave this way (e.g., `"abc" | string` reduces to `string`; `123 & number` reduces to `123`).  But TypeScript's type system isn't fully correct (and is not intended to be, see [TS Design Non-Goal #3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals)), and there are situations where convenience trumps correctness.

See [microsoft/TypeScript#16386](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386) for an old suggestion to fully implement the absorption laws, which was eventually closed as partially fixed and partially declined.

---

Object types like `A | B` tend not to be reduced because the more specific type often has properties would be completely forgotten after the absorption.  (For `B` that's the `bar` property.)  At the very least this isn't great for documentation.  Even in a fully sound type system people might want to *see* `A | B` in their documentation instead of `A`.

Furthermore, a few convenient but technically incorrect TypeScript constructs *do* care about such properties, so there's an observable difference between `A` and `A | B`.

---

One such construct is [using the `in` operator to distinguish between union members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).  For `A | B`, you can use the presence of `"bar"` as a key to narrow to `B`:

```
function f(obj: A | B) {
    if ("bar" in obj) {
        obj.bar.toUpperCase() // okay
    }
}
```

But for just `A` you cannot:

```
function f2(obj: A) {
    if ("bar" in obj) {
        obj.bar.toUpperCase() // error
    }
}
```

So `A | B` retains information the compiler uses to perform control flow analysis.  Of course this is very useful but is technically incorrect because it's unsafe:

```
class Z extends A {
    public bar: number = 1
}
f(new Z()); // <-- accepted but explodes
```

But, [as mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#15256, the pull request implementing `in` operator narrowing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152), the utility outweighs the incorrectness:

> The reality is that most unions are already correctly disjointed and don't alias enough to manifest the problem. Someone writing an `in` test is not going to write a "better" check; all that really happens in practice is that people add type assertions or move the code to an equally-unsound user-defined type predicate.

---

The flip side of this is another such construct: [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks).  When you assign an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) value to a place that isn't expecting a particular property to exist, you will get an error to warn you that the compiler will forget the property entirely and you might have made a mistake:

```
interface C { c: 1 }
const c: C = { c: 1, d: 2 }; // error
// ----------------> ~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, 
// and 'd' does not exist in type 'C'.
```

This is convenient and most people want this error, but it's technically a false warning because `{c: 1, d: 2}` *is* assignable to `C`.  Excess property checking introduces an *incompleteness* to the language that doesn't have to be there.

So here's where a union might be helpful:

```
interface D extends C { d: 2 }
const cd: C | D = { c: 1, d: 2 }; // okay
```

The type `C | D` is not reduced to `C`, and thus `{c: 1, d: 2}` is not seen to have any excess properties.  This is the flip side of `in` operator narrowing because the reason `d` isn't an excess property is because you can recover its type via `in` operator narrowing.

---

Excess property checking in concert with `in` operator narrowing essentially works like an alternative type system where TypeScript object types were closed/sealed/*exact* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  In that world, types would *prohibit* any extra properties.  And thus `B extends A` and `D extends C` would imply only a class/interface hierarchy, not a *type* hierarchy.  Meaning `X extends Y` no longer implies `X` is a subtype of `Y`, and thus `X | Y` would no longer be identical to `Y`.  In some sense, then, the lack of subtype reduction for unions of objects is to allow part of TypeScript to live in this alternate world of exact types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0AZgPYkBc0EALgE54B2A5tALzQBEHSAvkkqEgwAQtACmAD2piGAExjxkaDDnyFsYWpRr1mbTtz5IimBsGp4SDYgAoS2AFaV4AH2jCAlIhRo8RaDYcGrQc0IzQ9g5eSspokQB0wfHUJACq6OhitADCkGI2XgD0hREA1mAAnj6ofEYmZhZWxABMdo7O0dVh-oHBoeGRnbFxjomayWkZWbkQ+UUlWbQktF21-IJQ0ABa4lIy8nDeyli4BNDBlAyYALbYWfoAjLzGNgxiAO7bBR4A3NDF0AAPABaYHQMDAYBidDSWTnTDUXboEAkWRiCD8THAKw0cG0WiVZwAbQAuvoiW9PrACgAaaCU9wFEn8RjSWhECFiaDZRDQYCUB7QPjYhi4-nc-QIPkCumySjNIV-AGLZZIAGgjWarWggB80AAfmqSgB5RxiczQfBssAgaDXSoRBggCpUTLAPwu0oMEjvazoJaZWgWdF0o3guTQADkskj0FkJHR9JIiMkeFx4WoFUyUeykfiLIYbI5UOgABFdtI5DAeVK5dAFcKcYjgHWeW5y+wpeKHrL5Yr-iUSOUKkA)

Comment: Your first paragraph refers to the absorption laws, but it looks like you're describing subtype collapsing, given the Wikipedia page you linked and your description in the GitHub issue you linked (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386)? Or are they technically a subset of the absorption laws and the wording of your answer is just a little confusing?

Comment: Subtype collapsing is how union absorption would manifest in a type system, they're the same concept but using different wording

Comment: Got it, thanks :)